# Theme CCK fieldset

Tags: drupal, cck, drupal-theming

I am attempting to use the CCK theme_fieldgroup_fieldset($elements) hook to convert the fieldset to a two column layout.

I thought that this shouldn't be to hard because the individual fields are in the $elements variable so all I have to do is iterate over them and print them individually. the problem is that I have no way to tell if they have been excluded from display on the "Display Fields" tab of the content type.

Does anyone have any ideas for me? Am I trying to do this the hard way or what am I missing?

Comment: Something tells me if they are excluded from the view, it won't be available for the theme.

Comment: That is what I was hoping also, but when I got to working with the elements that I had available to me inside the theme_fieldgroup_fielset() function I was greatly disappointed to learn that they are available and there isn't even anything anywhere that I can use to to tell if they are excluded or not. Check out http://drupal.org/node/807330.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the solution that I came up with. The biggest problem is that it requires a database query for every field. These isn't the greatest, but it works so what can you say?

```
function _brioratheme_include_cck($field) {
  $query = "SELECT display_settings AS ds FROM {content_node_field_instance} WHERE field_name = '%s' LIMIT 1";
  $result = db_query($query, $field);
  if ($result) {
$row = db_fetch_object($result);
$display_settings = unserialize($row->ds);
return !$display_settings['full']['exclude'];
  }
}
```